# Getting the value of a Batch File Variable that is within another Variable

Tags: file, batch-file, variables

I am trying to create a batch file that adds a Desktop shortcut to a network share using 'mklink'.
My code worked fine, but I have now found some users that have their desktop redirected. To get around this I have tried using 'reg query' to get the current desktop location

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop  ^|findstr /ri "REG_EXPAND_SZ"') do set DTLOC=%%a
mklink %DTLOC%\"Shortcut Name" "\\NETWORK-PC\Share Name" /D
```

The problem now is that for a normal Desktop location 'reg query' returns the string `%USERPROFILE%\desktop` but as this is within a variable itself (DTLOC), it never resolves to the actual value.  So all I can get from DTLOC is `%USERPROFILE%\desktop` and not say `c:\users\username\desktop`. 
The actual command that is output from the batch file gives:

```
mklink %USERPROFILE%\desktop\"Shortcut Name" "\\NETWORK-PC\Share Name" /D
```

This causes the shortcut creation to fail with a 'file not found' error.

Is there a way to expand the output from 'reg query' to give the actual value, so that it can be used in the mklink command.

Comment: Insert a `call` command before: `call mklink %DTLOC%...`

Comment: Adding the call works perfectly, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `call`, which introduces another parsing phase of the command line, so nested variables become expanded too. In addition, let me recommend to adapt quotation as follows:

```cmd
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('
    reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop ^|findstr /ri "REG_EXPAND_SZ"
') do set "DTLOC=%%a"
call mklink "%DTLOC%\Shortcut Name" "\\NETWORK-PC\Share Name" /D
```